# Jmeter OsProcessSampler

Tags: jmeter

I'm doing a project and I'm trying to test it via JMeter with OS Process Sampler, but this error keeps popping up, I suppose it because there is no input given.

[JMeter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csUXV.png)

This is the menu I'm using
[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5UQu.png)

My question is, how can I set the input that is going to be used in the test?

Here are some images that may help:

[Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvnoQ.png)

[Main(what I'm running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Llz.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from your Python script, JMeter executes the script but it fails somewhere somehow (cannot read a file)

Your configuration looks correct.

Given this Python script:

```
import sys


def hello():
    print('Hello, ' + sys.argv[1])


hello()
```

it can be executed successfully in the [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

[image]

As you can see the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener contains Python script output.

So maybe you should set the "Working Directory" to where you Python script lives because with your settings it's executed in JMeter's "bin" directory context hence most probably it cannot read some file.

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)